# Does custom validator works in FormView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview, customvalidator, custom-validators

I have search through google and found that a lot of people is struggling with this issue but i still not found the right answer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/15jen.png

I have a form view and need to check that if the language code is duplicate or not, it have to be check on server-side script since it needed to be check through database.

updated 4 may 2011, 19.32
// I add attribute of form view here, so someone may point out if there is anything wrong.

```
<asp:FormView ID="fmvxLanguage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" DefaultMode="Insert"
    Visible="False" Width="95%" DataSourceID="odsLanguage" DataKeyNames="LanguageCode"
    CssClass="formViewAdd">
```

//

```
<dxe:ASPxButton ID="btnAddNewLanguage" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
Image-Url="~/images/icon/Save-icon.png" CommandName="Insert" Text="Save">
</dxe:ASPxButton>
```

I Use insert command as Insert in button, Cause Validation is set to true.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvdLanguageCodeNameDuplicate" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtLanguageCode" CssClass="IconValidation" 
                        ErrorMessage="&lt;img src=&quot;/images/icon/validation-Icon.png&quot;/&gt;     Language code name is duplicated." 
                        onservervalidate="cvdLanguageCodeNameDuplicate_ServerValidate">    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

Custom Validator is set as above

When i click the button and try putting the breakpoint at serverValidate event, i didn't even reach there

```
protected void cvdLanguageCodeNameDuplicate_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {

        if (LanguageHelper.HaveLanguageCode(args.Value))
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

As for now i use label instead of custom validator by checking if the value is valid or not in the event FormView_ItemInserting, if the value is not valid i just use e.Cancel (FormViewInsertEventArgs) and make the label visible. but still, i want to know if the custom validator is not works on formview or did i do something wrong.

Thank you.

**The following code is not about the question,** but it might be useful to someone search to this topic and might have same issue. i have to repeat this a lot of time so i make reusable class for this event ( using label as validator)

```
public class clsFormViewDuplicationValidationSetter
{
    #region Property


    public FormView FormView { get; set; }

    public delegate bool DelDuplicationValidationNameOnly(string pStrName);
    public delegate bool DelDuplicationValidationNameAndId(string pStrName, int primaryId);

    public DelDuplicationValidationNameOnly DuplicationValidationNameOnly;
    public DelDuplicationValidationNameAndId DuplicationValidationDelegationNameAndId;


    public TextBox TextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication { get; set; }
    public Label LabelDuplicationValidationMessage { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Pattern For Simple Duplication ValidationName and Id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pObjFormView">FormView</param>
    /// <param name="pObjTextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication">TextBoxName</param>
    /// <param name="pObjLabelDuplicationValidationMessage">Lable Showing Error Message</param>
    /// <param name="pObjDuplicationValidationNameAndId">Delegation for validation function (name and id)</param>
    public clsFormViewDuplicationValidationSetter(FormView pObjFormView, TextBox pObjTextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication, Label pObjLabelDuplicationValidationMessage, DelDuplicationValidationNameAndId pObjDuplicationValidationNameAndId)
    {
        this.FormView = pObjFormView;
        this.TextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication = pObjTextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication;
        this.LabelDuplicationValidationMessage = pObjLabelDuplicationValidationMessage;
        this.DuplicationValidationDelegationNameAndId = pObjDuplicationValidationNameAndId;
        FormView.ItemInserting += new FormViewInsertEventHandler(FormView_ItemInserting);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pattern For Simple Duplication Validation Name 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pObjFormView">FormView</param>
    /// <param name="pObjTextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication">TextBoxName</param>
    /// <param name="pObjLabelDuplicationValidationMessage">Lable Showing Error Message</param>
    /// <param name="pObjDuplicationValidationDelegation">Delegation for validation function (name)</param>
    public clsFormViewDuplicationValidationSetter(FormView pObjFormView, TextBox pObjTextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication, Label pObjLabelDuplicationValidationMessage, DelDuplicationValidationNameOnly pObjDuplicationValidationNameOnly)
    {
        this.FormView = pObjFormView;
        this.TextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication = pObjTextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication;
        this.LabelDuplicationValidationMessage = pObjLabelDuplicationValidationMessage;
        this.DuplicationValidationNameOnly = pObjDuplicationValidationNameOnly;
        FormView.ItemInserting += new FormViewInsertEventHandler(FormView_ItemInserting);
    }

    void FormView_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = TextBoxNameToCheckForDuplication.Text;


        bool IsDuplicate; 

         // when adding, id always 0
        if (DuplicationValidationDelegationNameAndId != null)
            IsDuplicate = DuplicationValidationDelegationNameAndId(name, 0);
        else
            IsDuplicate = DuplicationValidationNameOnly(name); 

        if (IsDuplicate)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            FormView.Visible = true;
            LabelDuplicationValidationMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

When using in Form Load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox objtxtLanguageCode= (TextBox)fmvxLanguage.FindControl("txtLanguageCode");
        Label objFormViewLabelDuplicationValidationMessage = (Label)fmvxLanguage.FindControl("lblFormViewDuplicate");

        clsFormViewDuplicationValidationSetter objFormViewDuplicationValidationSetter = new clsFormViewDuplicationValidationSetter(fmvxLanguage,objtxtLanguageCode,objFormViewLabelDuplicationValidationMessage,LanguageHelper.HaveLanguageCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out the more proper solution, we must 
Call Page.Validate() and checking if(Page.IsValid) before proceed.
if the ValidationGroup assigned, Call Page.Validate("groupNameHere")

Comment: This looks like perhaps it should have been an edit + extension of your previous answer, rather than a whole new answer...  You should consider combining them.

Comment: It works even if i don't use update panel, so i don't think i need to be combined it, do you need to use panel in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the validation group of the  button and CustomValidator .

try this

```
<dxe:ASPxButton ID="btnAddNewLanguage" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" Image-Url="~/images/icon/Save-icon.png" CommandName="Insert" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="V> 
</dxe:ASPxButton> 



<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvdLanguageCodeNameDuplicate" runat="server"                          ControlToValidate="txtLanguageCode" CssClass="IconValidation"                          ErrorMessage="&lt;img src=&quot;/images/icon/validation-Icon.png&quot;/&gt;     Language code name is duplicated."                          onservervalidate="cvdLanguageCodeNameDuplicate_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="V>    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it still not work.
Actually it works well in EditForm mode of DevExpress GridView without setting any validation group through, it is just not work in formview.

Answer (score 0):

Senior programmer in our team just found out that we need to put UpdateControlPanel in the CustomValidators in order to make it show on the EditFormView When Server-Side Validation has made and its valid state is false. For client side validation,its always work correctly.